# fisheye extrinsics vs estimateWorldCameraPose

Tags: matlab, fisheye

When calibrating a fisheye camera using Matlab, I get the fisheye intrinsics parameters:

```matlab
% Calibrate the camera using fisheye parameters
[cameraParams, imagesUsed, estimationErrors] = estimateFisheyeParameters(imagePoints, worldPoints, ...
    [mrows, ncols], ...
    'EstimateAlignment', true, ...
    'WorldUnits', 'millimeters');
```

The output of this function are the Scaramuzza parameters, in a shape very different from the classical 3x3 intrinsics matrix.

From this intrinsic parameters, I would like to estimate the pose of one my calibration pattern. So far I found two solutions but I do not know which one is more accurate.

First, I found I can directly feed the `extrinsics` function with the current intrinsics :

```matlab
% Extract intrinsics parameters
intrinsics = cameraParams.Intrinsics;

% Compute Rt matrix
[R,t] = extrinsics(imagePoints,worldPoints,intrinsics);
```

Looking inside the function, I can see this method uses the homography but kind of process by *magic* the Scaramuzza's intrinsics parameters. It is the same function used for both fisheye and non-fisheye models. Any idea the Scaramuzza parameters are processed here ?

Second solution is to use the function `estimateWorldCameraPose` which uses `P3P` and a RANSAC underneath. This function does not accept the raw fisheye parameters. One solution I found (https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/548787-function-estimateworldcamerapose-or-extrinsics-for-fisheyeparameters-is-missing-is-it-possible?s_tid=answers_rc1-2_p2_MLT) uses the function `undistortFisheyeImage` as a workaround to extract the 3x3 intrinsic parameters :

```matlab
[J,camIntrinsics] = undistortFisheyeImage(I,intrinsics)
```

Then I can feed the new intrinsics in the `estimateWorldCameraPose`.

Is this solution better ? How realiable this new intrinsics matrix is ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In all calibration methods (either a normal lens or fisheye lens), the extrinsic estimation uses the undistorted image points. So, the matlab function "extrinsics" should have the undistortion part(undistortion using Scaramuzza's lens distortion model) as well.
   Looking at the code "extrinsics", I see it is seperately handling the intrinsic when it is fisheye model.

```
if ~isa(cameraParams, 'fisheyeIntrinsics')
    if isa(cameraParams, 'cameraParameters')
        intrinsicParams = cameraParams;
    else
        intrinsicParams = cameraParams.CameraParameters;
    end

    intrinsics = intrinsicParams.IntrinsicMatrix;

    [rotationMatrix, translationVector] = vision.internal.calibration.extrinsicsPlanar(...
        imagePoints, worldPoints, intrinsics);
else
```

2. That is the only solution and only way to do that.

Comment: Your code only includes the "not fish eye" part. 
What do you mean by 2 ? I can clearly see two ways of doing it, the homography one or the P3P one.

Comment: Any idea the Scaramuzza parameters are processed here ? -> yes. that is not my code. just open up "extrinsics.m" and you will see the other part below "else ".

Comment: Is this solution better ? -> No, unless you write your own.

Comment: How realiable this new intrinsics matrix is ? -> I would say not too bad although if I have to do that I would directly calculate the extrinsic from the original image. That is unnecessary and redundant as well as lowering the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

`extrinsics` function both accept  fisheye and non-fisheye models,if accept fisheye model,the input argument `imagePoints` is distort points，while pin-hole(non-fisheye) model, it must accept undistort image points. it's internal implementation is both `vision.internal.calibration.extrinsicsPlanar.m` function.

```matlab
function [R,T] = extrinsicsPlanar(imagePoints, worldPoints, intrinsics)

A = intrinsics';

% Compute homography.
H = fitgeotrans(worldPoints, imagePoints, 'projective');
H = H.T';
h1 = H(:, 1);
h2 = H(:, 2);
h3 = H(:, 3);

lambda = 1 / norm(A \ h1);

% Compute rotation
r1 = A \ (lambda * h1);
r2 = A \ (lambda * h2);
r3 = cross(r1, r2);
R = [r1'; r2'; r3'];

% R may not be a true rotation matrix because of noise in the data.
% Find the best rotation matrix to approximate R using SVD.
[U, ~, V] = svd(R);
R = U * V';

% Compute translation vector.
T = (A \ (lambda * h3))';
```

EXTRINSICS Compute camera extrinsics from a planar calibration pattern,so this function is suit for you.

Pixel point de-aliasing was performed using the hidden method in the `fisheyeIntrinsics` class before processing the fisheye pixel points(before `extrinsicsPlanar` function).

```matlab
 %------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Determine the normalized 3D vector on the unit sphere
        %------------------------------------------------------------------
        function worldPoints = imageToNormalizedVector(this, imagePoints)
            %imageToNormalizedVector Determine the normalized 3D vector on
            %the unit sphere.
            %  worldPoints = imageToNormalizedWorld(intrinsics,imagePoints)
            %  maps image points to the normalized 3D vector emanating from
            %  the single effective viewpoint on the unit sphere.
            %
            %  Inputs:
            %  -------
            %  intrinsics        - fisheyeIntrinsics object.
            %
            %  imagePoints       - M-by-2 matrix containing [x, y]
            %                      coordinates of image points. M is the
            %                      number of points.
            %
            %  Output:
            %  -------
            %  worldPoints       - M-by-3 matrix containing corresponding
            %                      [X,Y,Z] coordinates on the unit sphere.
            
            points = vision.internal.inputValidation.checkAndConvertPoints(...
                imagePoints, 'fisheyeIntrinsics', 'imagePoints');
            
            if isa(points, 'single')
                points = double(points);
            end
            
            center = double(this.DistortionCenter);
            stretch = double(this.StretchMatrix);
            coeffs = double(this.MappingCoeffsInternal);
            
            % Convert image points to sensor coordinates
            points(:, 1) = points(:, 1) - center(1);
            points(:, 2) = points(:, 2) - center(2);
            points = stretch \ points';
            
            rho = sqrt(points(1, :).^2 + points(2, :).^2);
            f = polyval(coeffs(end:-1:1), rho);
            
            % Note, points could be invalid if f < 0
            worldPoints = [points; f]';
            
            nw = sqrt(sum(worldPoints.^2, 2));
            nw(nw == 0) = eps;
            
            worldPoints = worldPoints ./ horzcat(nw,nw, nw);
            worldPoints = cast(worldPoints, class(imagePoints));
        end
```

`estimateWorldCameraPose` function input argument `worldPoints` accept 3 columns positions. but you use coplaner coordinates, z=0,may be this function return `status` is 1 or 2. So your later solution may not better.